# Density of the image of the set $\lbrace (x,x), x\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace $ in $\mathbb{Z_{p}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

If $p,q$ are distinct primes, it is true that the subset $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$. However, is it true that  $\lbrace (x,x), x\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace $ is dense $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$? I think I need to prove the fact I must prove or disprove that my set is dense in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? (The topology here is the product topology, where each toology is induced by the usual p adic metric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individually, $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_q$ since that's how we get $p$- and $q$-adic numbers by [completion](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/dio2011-padic.pdf).

Even more we can solve $x \equiv a \mod p^k$ and $x \equiv \mod q^k$ simultaneously for any $p,q$ and any $k$ by the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) or [pigeonhole principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62565/what-is-your-favorite-application-of-the-pigeonhole-principle).

It works for any number of primes, simultaneously.  This is called **weak approximation**:

> **[Theorem 4.2](http://math.mit.edu/~ebelmont/785-notes.pdf)**
>
> Let $K$ be a field and $|\cdot|_1, \dots,|\cdot|_n$ be pairwise inequivalent $a_1, \dots, a_n \in K$ and $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$.  There exists an $x \in K$ satisfying $|x - a_i|_i < \epsilon_i$ simultaneously.