# Can the pigeonhole principle prove that the Pell equation $p^2-Nq^2=1$ always has a non-trivial solution?

Tags: number-theory, pigeonhole-principle, pell-type-equations

I remember a survey about the Pell equation. At the start it was claimed that it can be proven with the pigeonhole principle that the Pell-equation $$p^2-Nq^2=1$$ ($N$ is a positive integer not being a perfect square) always has a non-trivial solution ($p,q>0$)

Unfortunately, I do not remember whether the proof used the Dirichlet-approximation-theorem or modulo-arithmetic (and didn't understand, how it worked) , and I do not have access to the source anymore.

> Can the pigeonhole-principle actually prove that the Pell-equation is always solveable without using the continued-fraction-expansion of $\sqrt{N}$ ? And  if yes, how ?

Comment: Take a search engine you trust and feed it with pell and pigeonhole.

Comment: Does this help http://math.stackexchange.com/a/207775/186189

Comment: @kingW3 Seems to be exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: Looking closer at the proof , I am stuck : I do not understand why we can conclude $|p^2-Dq^2|<\frac{(q+1)\sqrt{D}}{q}$. It is clear that $|q\sqrt{D}-p|\le \frac{1}{q}$, but what about $|p+q\sqrt{D}|$ ?

Comment: I hope that the proof does not contain a serious error...

Comment: If it was possible to prove that
$$ x^2-Dy^2 = 1 $$
always has a solution by the pigeonhole principle only, it would be probably possible to show that 
$$ x^2-Dy^2 = -1$$
always has a solution by the same lines. But that is simply wrong. Arithmetic has to play a major role at some point.