# Given any $10$ people in a room, prove that among them there are either $3$ that know each other or $4$ that do not know each other.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, extremal-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Given any $10$ people in a room, prove that among them there are either $3$ that know each other or $4$ that do not know each other. (Assume that if A knows B, then B knows A.)

Could the pigeonhole principle be used for this? If so, how? I have a feeling it can be used but im not sure where to apply it just yet.

Comment: Have you ever heard anything about Ramsey, Ramsey's Theorem, or Ramsey Theory in general?  You are effectively being asked to show $R(3,4)\leq 10$

Comment: You can do a lot better at last check ...  At least 5 monochromatic triangles ...

Comment: Slightly harder is showing $R(3,4)=9$.  You can see it as part of [this video by Imre Leader](https://maths.org/leader-order-jun14-video) (around 23:30 to 33:00 using a parity argument)

Answer (score 1):

Choose one of the present people, say $A$. The rest are split into two groups- those that know $A$ (let's say, group $T$) and those that don't (let's say, group $S$). There are just two possibilities: either $|S| ≥ 6$ or $|T| ≥ 4$ (or otherwise $|S∪T| < 9$ which is a contradiction).

If $|S| ≥ 6$, then there has to be $3$ members of $S$ that don't know each other ([a well known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42629/943723)). Together with $A$, they form a group of four mutual strangers.

If $|T| ≥ 4$, then either they all don't know each other (in which case we are already done), or some two are acquaintances. In the latter case, together with $A$ these two form a triple of mutual acquaintances.

This completes the proof.

Comment: You have swapped know and don't know, though it is not important. The extension to $9$ in a room says something similar, but for every point you need $|S|\ge 6$ (done as in the $10$ case), or $|T|\ge 4$ (done as in the $10$ case), or $|S|=5$ and $|T|=3$.  But the last of these is impossible as it would lead to the number of pairs who know each other being $\frac{27}{2}$ and the number of pairs who do not know each other being \frac{45}{2}$, neither of which are integers

Comment: In fact you can prove $1$ monochrome triangle for $6$    ,$2$ triangles for $7$ , etc.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing that out. Please check whether it's okay now.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Actually there are (at least) $2$ monochromatic triangles for $6$ vertices, $4$ monochromatic triangles for $7$ vertices.

Comment: @bof yeah technically any even number n-4

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Huh? The minimum possible number of monochromatic triangles in a $2$-coloring of the edges of the complete grapg $K_n$ is given by [Goodman's formula](https://oeis.org/A014557): $$\binom n3-\left\lfloor\frac n2\left\lfloor\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Okay fine I'm not formula based. Once you show two for n equal to 6 you can easily show n-4 for even values is possible. Was my point.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Oh, never mind Goodman's formula. Once you show that in a $2$ -coloring of $K_6$ there are $2$ monochromatic triangles, i.e. 10% of the $20$ triangles, it follows that in a $2$-coloring of $K_n$ where $n\ge6$, at least 10% of the triangles are monochromatic, i.e. at least $\binom n3/10$ of them. So for $n=10$ there are at least $12$ monochromatic triangles. (Actually, by Goodman's theorem, there must be at least $20$.)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, let A be an arbitrary person among the 10 people, and denote the other 9 people from $A_1$ to $A_9$.

**Case I**: A knows at least 4 of $A_i$'s. Then assume A knows $A_1,A_2,\cdots, A_5$.

if $A_i, A_j$ knows each other, then we have a triangle $A, A_i, A_j$. Otherwise, $A_1,\cdots, A_5$ constitutes a set of 5 people that don't know each other

**Case II:** A doesn't know at least 6 of $A_i$'s. Then consider 6 people $A_1, A_2, A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6$.

Then apply the following lemma shall yield the easy solution:

**Lemma**
There exist three people who mutually know/or don't know each other among 6 random people.

There's a stronger lemma I think you also might want to consider, that is to prove that there are two triangles of people who mutually know/don't know each other.

Comment: In case I, you meant to write $A$ knows at least $5$ of the $A_i$s.

Answer (score 0):

Answered the same at a duplicate, but as it was closed I will transfer it here. Basically we need to show that: $R(4,3) \leq 10 $ but:

$$ R(4,3) \leq R(4,2)+ R(3,3) = 4+ 6 =10 $$

And it is pretty straightforward to show that $R(4,2)=4$ and that $R(3,3)=6$